# Sending any SMS message displays an icon to display the message is "pending to networks" and "delivered to network" in Andorid

Tags: android, sms, android-intent

Sending any SMS message displays an icon to display the message is "pending 
to networks" and "delivered to network" but never displays the "delivered 
to handset" (or "delivered upstream") SMS status.

What is problem ? i am unable to simulate this issue ? please help ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to setup broadcast receivers and also declare them in your manifest file. The Sms Manager has two places where the broad cast receiver works

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

SentPI and delivered PI will do the intended work that you want.

Answer (score 0):

i think the following link solve your problem,

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

use your code instead of Toast message.